# Create multi dimensional JSON structure from HTML div structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I have a site where I'm rendering blocks from a JSON file where the user can then sort blocks if they want it in another way that I then save to the database. My problem is how to keep the same structure as it's not a flat JSON structure.

Example from JSON file:

```
[{
    "part": 0,
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "template",
            "id": "SOME_ID_0"
        },
        {
            "type": "template",
            "id": "SOME_ID_1"
        },
    ]
},
{
    "part": 1,
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "template",
            "id": "SOME_ID_2"
        },
        {
            "type": "template",
            "id": "SOME_ID_3"
        },
    ]
}]
```

From the JSON file, each object within "blocks" are rendered and can be rearranged so block in part 0 could have 3 blocks, and part 1 could have only one block etc. The reason for why each block is within "part" and not just flat is because I render only some parts in some special cases.

HTML example:

```
<div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="ADD 'part' JSON HERE SOMEHOW?">
  <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_0&quot;}">Some info 1</div>
  <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_1&quot;}">Some info 2</div>
</div>
<div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="ADD 'part' JSON HERE SOMEHOW?">
  <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_2&quot;}">Some info 3</div>
  <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_3&quot;}">Some info 4</div>
</div>
```

For the jquery/ajax code, I use push:

```
  // Save block structure for ÅR
  var blockContent=[];
  $("#myForm").find('.blockContent').each(function(i,item){
    blockContent.push($(item).data('blockcontent'));
  });

$.ajax({
url:"/ajax/saveBlockStructure",
method:"POST",
async:true,
data: {
  id: "{{ $id }}",
  _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
  blockStructure: JSON.stringify(blockContent)
}
```

});
}

For the PHP/Laravel code, I just have a loop that iterates the json file and I don't think that is necessary to show here.

I don't know how but I guess I should somehow add the start of the part/blocks in the parent div and end it and then start on the next part?

Comment: You would want a different class for the `part` wrapper element and pass the `part` value to an attribute. Then loop all those `part` elements with internal loop to build it's `blocks` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the outer class to `part` and use a `data-part` attribute.

Then it is a simple nested `map()` to create the data

```js
const data = $('.part').map(function() {
  const $el = $(this),
    blocks = $el.children().map(function() {
      return $(this).data('blockcontent');
    }).get()

  return {
    part: $el.data('part'),
    blocks: blocks
  }

}).get()

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="part" data-part="0">
  <div class="block" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_0&quot;}">Some info 1</div>
  <div class="block" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_1&quot;}">Some info 2</div>
</div>
<div class="part" data-part="1">
  <div class="block" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_2&quot;}">Some info 3</div>
  <div class="block" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_3&quot;}">Some info 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked just the way I wanted it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, by selecting only the direct children each step, this is an example that will work only with one level deep.

I personnaly would choose to distinguish semantically the classes and data attributes though (for example with `.blockPart` and `data-blockpartid`) but it really depends how far you want to go in the nesting and how you build your HTML.

```js
// Save block structure for ÅR
var blocks=[];
//you might need to adapt the selector if "part" blocks are not on top level of the form
$("#myForm").find('> .blockContent').each(function(i,item){
  var part = {
    id: $(item).data('blockcontent'),
    blocks: [],
  };
  blocks.push(part); //filling it after works because of reference
  $(item).find('> .blockContent').each(function(i2,subitem){
    part.blocks.push($(subitem).data('blockcontent'));
  });
});

console.log(blocks);
console.log(JSON.stringify(blocks));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="0">
    <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_0&quot;}">Some info 1</div>
    <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_1&quot;}">Some info 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="1">
    <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_2&quot;}">Some info 3</div>
    <div class="blockContent" data-blockcontent="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;template&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;SOME_ID_3&quot;}">Some info 4</div>
  </div>
</form>
```